# Link to Directly View Default List of Contacts (Drupal)

Tags: drupal, search, menu

I would like to be able to link directly to the page listing contacts (same as if searching for a wildcard (searching without entering . Even better would be able to pass in variables through the link to filter the results.

At the very minimum I would like to show the list of contacts as if you just go to the search bar and press enter. I'm looking for a way to directly link to the list of contacts.

Is this possible?

**Clarification and thoughts...**
Right now it appears that the only way you can repeatedly search for contacts is to manually do a search. This is tedious and very limited. Ideally there would be a way to pass in parameters through the URL to get search results. This would allow us to have direct links to a specific set of search results.

Comment: i think you need to expand on the requirements. if you want a View that lists all Contacts with an Exposed Filter that uses 'contains' then yes this is possbible, but i don't think that is what you are asking

Comment: At the very minimum I would like to show the list of contacts as if you just go to the search bar and press enter. Just the default built-in contact search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the default (or customized) Constituent Report ( /civicrm/report/instance/1)

Add the URL to your default Drupal 7 shortcut list ( /admin/config/user-interface/shortcut/shortcut-set-1)

The user clicks one time, and sees the contact list you want, without any use of views.

Comment: IMHO this is the best solution at this point in time until the CiviCRM built-in search functionality is improved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no navigation that sends you to a 'list' of contacts. First you need to be clear on what that 'list' would show. Is it just the list that you get from going to Advanced Search and clicking on 'search' which is same as clicking in Quick Search and hitting 'enter/return' on your keyboard. If you don't want to build a View then perhaps make a Profile, add the fields you want in it, and set them to 'searchable' - but of course that all begs the question of 'what do you want people to be able to do once they see this list' which is something you haven't mentioned.

Comment: I just want the list to be the default as if you clicked search without entering any parameters.

Comment: not currently available but assume this would be a trivial extension to make if you are up to tackling or funding it.

Answer (score 0):

What CMS? Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress?

Why not make a View (if using Drupal) ?

Comment: Drupal (in the title). Sure I could make a view, but that seems a little much for such a simple thing as listing contacts. I'd be pretty disappointed if that is our only option.

Comment: So you want to send people to /civicrm/contact/search? ?

Comment: I want to send them to /civicrm/contact/search but have the link show the default listing of contacts, without clicking find.

Comment: Also, I read somewhere that Views support was being dropped, is that still the case?

Comment: where did you read that - are we talking d7 or d8?